Is there a mistake in this question from Mathematical Logic by Chiswell and Hodges?
I'm writing a solutions manual to Mathematical Logic by Chiswell and Hodges (just for fun). I think there's a mistake in Exercise 5.6.4 (b). I think the claim is false. But, I'd like to confirm this and make sure I haven't missed something.
Context: It's in chapter 5 on quantifier free logic. It concerns languages that have first-order signatures but none of their formulas involve quantifiers. $LR$ means the language of relations, qf means quantifier free (so all closed formulas of qf $LR$ contain no occurrences of variables). $LR(\sigma$) means the dialect of the language of relations with first-order signature $\sigma$. The authors define a first-order signature, $\sigma$, as an ordered $4$-tuple, $\sigma=(Co , Fu, Re, r)$ where $Co$, $Fu$, and $Re$ are the set of constant symbols, function symbols, and relation symbols of the (dialect of the) language respectively. $r$ is a the arity (or rank) function on the function symbols and relation symbols. That is, $r: Fu\cup Re\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. The notation $\models_{A}\psi$ means $A$ is a model of $\psi$ where $A$ is a $\sigma$-structure and $\psi$ is a formula of $LR(\sigma)$ for some signature $\sigma$. The notation $\Gamma\models_{\sigma}\psi$ means that every $\sigma$-structure that is a model of $\Gamma$ (a set of formulas of $LR(\sigma)$) is a model of $\psi$ (a formula of $LR(\sigma)$).
Exercise 5.6.4
(a) (A version of the Principle of Irrelevance for qf $LR$) Suppose $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are signatures with $\rho\subseteq\sigma$, $A$ is a $\sigma$-structure and $B$ is a $\rho$-structure with the same domain as $A$, and $s_{A}=s_{B}$ for every symbol $s\in\rho$. Show that if $\phi$ is a qf sentence of $LR(\rho)$, then $\models_{A}\phi$ if and only if $\models_{B}\phi$.
(b) Using (a), show that if $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are signatures with $\rho\subseteq\sigma$, $\Gamma$ is a set of of qf sentences of $LR(\sigma)$ and $\psi$ is a qf sentence of $LR(\sigma)$, then $(\Gamma\models_{\sigma}\psi)$ holds if and only if $(\Gamma\models_{\rho}\psi)$ holds.
I've proved (a). However, I think (b) is false because the `left-to-right' direction can fail. I think the authors intended $\Gamma$ to be a set of qf sentences of $LR(\rho)$ and $\psi$ to be a qf sentence of $LR(\rho)$. (Side note: the notation $\rho\subseteq\sigma$ may be a little sloppy since the authors define signatures as ordered $4$-tuples but the intended meaning is that every symbol of $\rho$ is a symbol of $\sigma$.) I've constructed a counterexample where $\Gamma\models_{\sigma}\psi$ but not $\Gamma\models_{\rho}\psi$. In summary it works like this, just take $\Gamma$ to be a set of formulas of $LR(\rho)$ and $\psi$ to be a formula of $LR(\sigma)$ but not $LR(\rho)$ such that $\Gamma\models_{\sigma}\psi$. Then construct a $\rho$-structure which models $\Gamma$. It cannot model $\psi$ because $\psi$ is not a formula of $LR(\rho)$. Here's one possible way:
Take the signature of arithmetic, $\sigma_{\text{arith}}=(\{\bar{0}\},\{\bar{S},\bar{+},\bar{\cdot}\},\emptyset , \{(\bar{S},1),(\bar{+},2),(\bar{\cdot},2)\})$ and $\rho=(\{\bar{0}\},\{\bar{S}\},\emptyset , \{(\bar{S},1)\})$. In words, $\rho$ is the signature of arithmetic without a the binary function symbols $\bar{+}$ and $\bar{\cdot}$. Let $\Gamma=\{(\bar{0}=\bar{0})\}$ and $\psi$ be $((\bar{0}=\bar{0})\vee (\bar{0}=\bar{+}(\bar{0},\bar{0})))$. Now every $\sigma_{\text{arith}}$-structure which is a model of $\Gamma$ is also a model of $\psi$. That is, $\Gamma\models_{\sigma}\psi$. Every $\rho$-structure models $\Gamma$ and doesn't model $\psi$ because $\rho$ doesn't have the symbol $\bar{+}$. So no $\rho$-structure can interpret $\bar{+}(\bar{0},\bar{0})$.
Am I correct that the claim in (b) is false for the reason I've given? Do you think $\Gamma$ should instead be a set of formulas of $LR(\rho)$ and $\psi$ a formula of $LR(\rho)$?
I've checked the corrigenda for the book released by the authors. There's no correction to the exercise.
Edit:
(1) I should add that the propositional analogue of this result in the text (page 69, Exercise 3.5.4), takes $\Gamma$ to be a set of formulas of $LP(\rho)$ and $\psi$ to be a formula of $LP(\rho)$ where $LP$ is the language of propositions and $\rho , \sigma$ are propositional signatures.
(2) Corrected some typos.

I agree with you that $\Gamma$ and $\psi$ should be in the smaller signature $\rho$. Also, $\phi$ should be $\psi$.

Right. It should be $LR(\rho)$, not $LR(\sigma)$.

@AndreasBlass Thanks both of you. I'll make the edits to the $\phi$s for future readers. But I'll keep them in part (a) since they are $\phi$s in the book.

I have scrutinised the relevant parts of the book. In order for the involvement of a wider readership for the discussion, I shall present first a usual statement and proof of a closely connected theorem, then a comparison of the two.
Preliminary remarks.
If $\Gamma$ is a set of quantifier-free sentences of $LR(\sigma)$, then we say that a $\sigma$-structure $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $\Gamma$ if $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of every sentence in $\Gamma$ and we write
$$\Gamma\vDash_{\sigma}\phi$$
to indicate that every $\sigma$-structure that is a model of  $\Gamma$ is also a model of $\phi$. In a usual notation, we can express this as
$$\mathcal{M}\vDash_{\sigma}\Gamma\implies\mathcal{M}\vDash_{\sigma}\phi$$
We consider two signatures $\rho$ and $\sigma$ such that $\rho\subseteq\sigma$. We denote their universes of discourse by $\mathsf{N}$ and $\mathsf{M}$, respectively. $\mathsf{N}\subseteq\mathsf{M}$ and the following interpretations are specified accordingly:

$R^{\rho} = R^{\sigma}\cap\mathsf{N}^{n}$ for an n-ary relation symbol in $LR(\sigma)$.
$f^{\rho} =\left.f^{\sigma}\right|_\mathsf{N}$, i.e.,   the restriction of $f$ to $\mathsf{N}$ for n-ary (term-forming) function symbol in $LR(\sigma)$.
$c^{\rho} = c^{\sigma}$ for an individual constant symbol $c$ is  in $LR(\sigma)$.

Crucial point 1. We tend to reason over the relations and functions intensionally, however, formally, they should be regarded extensionally. For example, consider the familiar structural relations:
$$\langle\mathbb{N}, +,\times, <, 0, 1\rangle\subset\langle\mathbb{Q}, +, \times, <, 0, 1\rangle\subset\langle\mathbb{R}, +, \times, <, 0, 1\rangle$$
Stipulated in this substructural schema, $\langle\mathbb{N}, +,\times, <, 0, 1\rangle$ is an extensional restriction of $\langle\mathbb{Q}, +,\times, <, 0, 1\rangle$ to $\mathbb{N}$, likewise, $\langle\mathbb{Q}, +,\times, <, 0, 1\rangle$ is an extensional restriction of $\langle\mathbb{R}, +,\times, <, 0, 1\rangle$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, as the definitions cited above indicate. Hence, for instance, we cannot intensionally make $+$ void and keep $\times$; whenever there is a pair of numbers such that $1\times 2$, then necessarily, there is a corresponding pair $1+2$.
Crucial point 2. The proposition stated in the question is in the biconditional form, $p\leftrightarrow q$. So, what we aim to find out is whether $p\rightarrow q$ and $q\rightarrow p$ stand or fall together.
Crucial point 3. We work with sentences, i.e., a closed formula that is determinately true or false in a model. Furthermore, they are quantifier-free. We can see the significance of these in the following example:
Take the universe of $\sigma$-structure $\mathbb{N}$ and of $\rho$- structre $\mathbb{N}\!\setminus\!0$. Then, the formula $\exists y(y<x)$  would be true in $\sigma$-structure, but false in $\rho$-structure if $x=1$. With quantifier-free formulas, carrying on with the present case, we take the open formula $y<x$ and assign members from the universe of the substructure (viz., $\mathbb{N}\!\setminus\!0$) to $x$ and $y$, thus obtain the pairs $1<2,\:3<5,\:9\not<6\ldots$
Now, we can follow on with the theorem phrased for the present context: Suppose $\mathcal{N}$ is a $\rho$-model of a formula $\phi$, $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-model of the formula, and $a\in\mathsf{N}$ (for simplicity, considering a single variable case assigned to $a$). Then
$$\mathcal{N}\vDash\phi(a)\iff\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a)$$
The proof is by the familiar induction on the complexity of formulas:

For all terms $t$: $t^{\mathcal{N}}(a) = t^{\mathcal{M}}(a)$
If $\phi$ is $t_{1} = t_{2}$, then

$$\mathcal{N}\vDash\phi(a)\iff t_1^{\mathcal{N}}(a) = t_2^{\mathcal{N}}(a)\iff t_1^{\mathcal{M}}(a) = t_2^{\mathcal{M}}(a) \iff\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a)$$

If $\phi$ is $R(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n})$, then
$$\mathcal{N}\vDash\phi(a)\iff (t_1^{\mathcal{N}}(a),\ldots, t_n^{\mathcal{N}}(a))\in R^{\mathcal{N}}$$

$$\iff (t_1^{\mathcal{N}}(a),\ldots, t_n^{\mathcal{N}}(a))\in R^{\mathcal{M}}$$
$$\iff (t_1^{\mathcal{M}}(a),\ldots,t_n^{\mathcal{M}}(a)) \in R^{\mathcal{M}}$$
$$\iff\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a)$$

Similarly for the functions.
Suppose that the statement holds for a formula $\psi$ and $\phi$ is $\neg\psi$. Then,

$$\mathcal{N}\vDash\neg\phi(a)\iff\mathcal{N}\not\vDash\psi(a)\iff\mathcal{M}\not\models\psi(a)\iff\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a)$$

Suppose that the statement holds for $\psi_{0}$ and $\psi_{1}$ and $\phi$ is $\psi_{0}\wedge\psi_{1$}$. Then,

$\mathcal{N}\vDash\phi(a)\iff\mathcal{N}\vDash\psi_0(a)\mbox{ and }\mathcal{N}\vDash\psi_1(a)\iff\mathcal{M}\vDash\psi_0(a)\mbox{ and }\mathcal{M}\vDash\psi_1(a)\iff\mathcal{M}\vDash\phi(a)$
$\therefore\quad$ By compositionality, the theorem follows for any quantifier-free formula.
Notice that in this version, the smaller universe of discourse is taken as the limiting condition. However, the exercise specifies a common universe. There remains taking the symbols in the signature of the substructure as the limiting condition. Hence, there is indeed, an error; $LR(\sigma)$ should be replaced with $LR(\rho)$.
